# Shall answering a user's query in the own answer's comment-section not be rewarded (not enough)?

Tags: discussion, upvotes, duplicate-answers, unaccepted-answer

A few days ago I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598853/new-project-wizard-bugged-on-netbeans/35598967#35598967), to which the user requested for more help in the comment-section of my answer.

I then extended [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35598967/3482140) in the comment section, stating what is to be done to restore the functionality in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35598853/new-project-wizard-bugged-on-netbeans/35598967#comment58885006_35598967).

Lastly, OP answered his/her question which was an exact solution prescribed by me in the comment. I requested him to accept and upvote my answer, to which he/she didn't reply later(yet).

Is this behaviour acceptable? Shouldn't the OP have accepted my answer after my reminder?

This somehow discourages me to write further answers of questions related to [netbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/netbeans). I have already faced [several other such cases answering questions on NetBeans tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:3482140%20[netbeans]) (see 0 score answers).

Comment: yes it is completely acceptable; they are not entitled to an answer anymore than you are entitled to a checkmark or an upvote, expecting anything else is unreasonable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't force people to accept your answer.

If your answer is a good one it will likely gain upvotes over time. If it's better than the accepted answer it will outscore it eventually, that's your reward.

It's much better to answer because you want to help everyone that if you just concentrate on the question asker. There's nothing more you can do in this case except shrug and move on.

Comment: OK, I agree. *(To self -> this means I've to stop answering questions related to [tag:netbeans])*!